# No stores in the coordinator are configured to use CloudKit

Tags: core-data, swiftui, cloudkit, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

Upon attempting to run

```
container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "Test")
container.initializeCloudKitSchema()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
NSLocalizedFailureReason=Couldn't initialize CloudKit schema because no stores in the coordinator are configured to use CloudKit
```

I'm building a CoreData/CloudKit app on iOS with SwiftUI.

Any ideas on what this error means? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It does not look you configured your project properly - follow https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/setting_up_core_data_with_cloudkit.